# SFML не воспроизводится звук

Tags: c++, указатели, sfml

Я захотел написать свой менеджер для управлением звуками, и получилось так, что по завершению программы звук не воспроизводится, но если я уберу добавление 2 и 3-его звука, все будет работать (причем неважно, какой будет файл `walking_1.wav` или `walking_2.wav`).

`Audio.hpp`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include "specialtools.hpp"

class Audio{
    public:
    
    vector<sf::SoundBuffer>         sBuffers;
    vector<shared_ptr<sf::Sound>>   sh_ptr_sounds;
    vector<string>                  names;

    void newSound(string name, string fname){
        sBuffers.push_back(sf::SoundBuffer{});
        sBuffers[sBuffers.size()-1].loadFromFile(fname);
        cout<<"[ADD NEW SOUND] last buffer index: "<<sBuffers.size()-1<<endl;

        sh_ptr_sounds.push_back(make_shared<sf::Sound>(sf::Sound{}));
        sh_ptr_sounds[sh_ptr_sounds.size()-1]->setBuffer(sBuffers[sBuffers.size()-1]);
        cout<<"[ADD NEW SOUND] last sound index: "<<sh_ptr_sounds.size()-1<<endl;

        names.push_back(name);
        cout<<"[ADD NEW SOUND] name: "<<name<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }

    void playSound(string name){
        cout<<"Index of sound: "<<index(names, name)<<endl;
        sh_ptr_sounds[index(names, name)]->play();
    }

    Audio(){}
};
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include "Audio.hpp"

int main(){
    Audio aud;
    aud.newSound("1", "res/Sounds/walking_1.wav");
    aud.newSound("2", "res/Sounds/walking_2.wav");
    aud.newSound("3", "res/Sounds/walking_3.wav");
    aud.playSound("1");
    cin.get();
}
```

Вывод:

```
[ADD NEW SOUND] last buffer index: 0
[ADD NEW SOUND] last sound index: 0
[ADD NEW SOUND] name: 1

[ADD NEW SOUND] last buffer index: 1
[ADD NEW SOUND] last sound index: 1
[ADD NEW SOUND] name: 2

[ADD NEW SOUND] last buffer index: 2
[ADD NEW SOUND] last sound index: 2
[ADD NEW SOUND] name: 3

Index of sound: 0
```

В `specialtools.hpp` хранится только функция `index`, и подключаются библиотеки `iostream`, `memory` и `vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экземпляры `sf::Sound` сохраняют ссылку на передаваемые в них экземпляры `sf::SoundBuffer`, соответственно переданные экземпляры `sf::SoundBuffer` должны оставаться валидными, пока используются. Однако при добавлении новых объектов в `sBuffers` все ссылки на хранившиеся там ранее объекты протухают

Тут имеет смысл держать один контейнер, который не будет инвалидировать ссылки на свои элементы.

```
   class t_Sound
   {
       sf::SoundBuffer m_buffer;
       sf::Sound m_sound;
       ::std::string m_name;

       public: explicit
       t_Sound(::std::string const & name, ::std::string const & fname)
       :   m_buffer{LoadFromFile(fname)}
       ,   m_sound{m_buffer}
       ,   m_name{name}
       {}

       private:
       t_Sound(t_Sound const &) = delete;

       private: void
       operator =(t_Sound const &) = delete;

       private: static sf::SoundBuffer
       LoadFromFile(::std::string const & fname)
       {
           sf::SoundBuffer buffer{};
           if (not buffer.loadFromFile(fname))
           {
               throw ::std::runtime_error{fname};
           }
           return buffer;
       }
   };

   ::std::vector<::std::shared_ptr<t_Sound>> m_sounds;

   void
   newSound(::std::string const & name, ::std::string const & fname)
   {
       m_sounds.emplace_back(::std::make_shared<t_Sound>(name, fname));
   }
```

Comment: Т.е. может быть только 1 буфер?

Comment: @Hanji Нет, почему же. Только надо делать так, что ссылки на используемые буферы не протухали. В моем коде `Sound` ссылается на `SoundBuffer` который является полем в том же объекте и гарантировано живет дольше.

Comment: Извините, но я еще немного новичок в C++ и мне код немного не понятен...